# Unable to find the element using selenium, code developed in MVC

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

[attached the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qogOX.png) I am unable to find the element using `Xpath`. The code is developed in `MVC` framework, the code is coming from partial-view. please check the attached image and help

```
<html class=" js flexbox no-touch backgroundsize boxshadow  
csstransforms" style="">
 <head>
<body>
<header class="header header-waterfall affix-top">
<div class="menu-wrapper pull-left" role="navigation">
<ul class="nav nav1" role="menubar">
<li role="menuitem">
<a href="#">
<span class="icon icon-lg">menu</span>
</a>
<div id="menu_nav" class="mega-menu" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" 
style="">
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 pull-left">
<ul class="nav nav-list pull-right" style="padding: 6px 0px; cursor: 
pointer;">
</header>
```

Tried with `span`, `li` role etc. But, maximum times I got error like, not interacted.

> FAILED: testCheckFarmerData
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class= 'nav nav 1']/li/a/span"}
>   Command duration or timeout: 30.13 seconds

Comment: Share you selenium code which have you tried....

Comment: and what do you mean by unable to find the element??.. is there any exception?? please share it also as well

Comment: please find the attached image for selenium code. Tried with span, li role etc. But, maximum times I got error like, not interacted. FAILED: testCheckFarmerData
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class= 'nav nav 1']/li/a/span"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.13 seconds

Comment: tried with all the means and approached the developer, he says, it is developed in MVC framework and the top menu is pulled from Partial-view

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("menu")));
el.click();
```

**Edited1** :- You can perform `click` as by using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("menu")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

**Edited2** :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@cla‌​ss='nav nav1']/descendant::span[contains(.,'menu')]")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Wonderful! It is working at last. Struggled from 2 days

Comment: it is not working in FF also in chrome some times. Its working only in IE

Comment: @SuneelKuppili What do you mean it is not working in FF also in chrome some times?? is there exception??

Comment: @SuneelKuppili If there is timeOut, you need to increase your time from 10 second to more..

Comment: Again i am getting same error, I have tried giving increased time upto 100ms. This is the error: FAILED: testCheckFarmerData
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds

Comment: This is the error with FF driver: FAILED: testCheckFarmerData
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 34 milliseconds

Comment: @SuneelKuppili if you are checking for visibility condition this error will never throw..as my provided code always will throw `TimeoutException` if element visibility condition not true.. might be you are going to find element as `driver.findElement(By.linkText("menu"));` that's why you are getting the exception..try with `WebDriverWait` as provided..

Comment: I am using your code only I have not changed, I just changed to Xpath instead of LinkText like - WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
    WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("html/body/header/div[1]/ul/li/a/span")));
    el.click();

Comment: @SuneelKuppili I got it.. you should try `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` instead of `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` because `elementToBeClickable` checking visibility and enable,...and if not getting success.. try using  `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click..see updated answer...hope it helps..:)

Comment: Sorry, not working. increased the delay too to 60. Not sure about the application behavior. It was working yesterday in IE, today it is not working. Also, chrome was working yesterday inconsistently. Today it was working in early hours, now it is not working.

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b) on port 47274
Only local connections are allowed.
FAILED: testCheckFarmerData
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)

Comment: @SuneelKuppili could you tell me when this error occurred during find element or during clicking??

Comment: And did you tried `By.linkText` or `By.XPath` to locate??

Comment: find element. because the element is not visible. If the element is found it can click.

Comment: @SuneelKuppili Ok once use `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy` and try to click using `JavascriptExecutor` as `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//ul[@class='nav nav1']/descendant::span[contains(.,'menu')]")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el);` and let me know..

Comment: Unable to save with above code. says Cp1252 cannot be mapped. May be because of ::

Comment: But, ran the test. It is failed. Says, not valid xpath. SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//ul[@cla??ss='nav nav1']/descendant::span[contains(.,'menu')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Comment: @SuneelKuppili see the update **edited2**..use it... your exception occured due to `''` you are providing same both inside and outside of the xpath.. any way try with **edited2** answer and let me know

Comment: No. I have tried with 60 also. FAILED: testCheckFarmerData
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //ul[@cla??ss='nav nav1']/descendant::span[contains(.,'menu')]

Comment: @SuneelKuppiliis there present span with text `menu` on your page??

Comment: No other span with Menu

Comment: @SuneelKuppili Menu or menu??

Comment: @SuneelKuppili as you posted exception says Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //ul[@cla??ss='nav nav1']/descendant::span[contains(.,'menu')] while correct xpath is `//ul[@class='nav nav1']/descendant::span[contains(.,'menu')]`....why append `??` with class...check it please